# Why does this return a list of generator objects?

Tags: python, tuples

lets say I have some code:

```
a= {'first': 2, 'second': 3}
b = {'first':4, 'second': 6}
c=[a,b]
d = ['first', 'second']
q = [(item[col] for col in d) for item in c]
```

for some reason (despite looking around stackoverflow) q continues to be a list of generator objects

```
print q
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000002875750>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000002875798>]
```

however when I just do a basic iteration:

```
x = []
for item in c:
y = []
for col in d:
    y.append(item[col])

x.append(tuple(y))
```

I get the expected values:

```
print x
[(2, 3), (4, 6)]
```

Why doesn't the first way return the same as the second?  I don't see the difference.  thanks-

Comment: Because parenthesis by themselves are literal syntax for creating generator expressions, if you want to create a tuple you need to pass your generarot expression to `tuple` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to:

```
q = [tuple(item[col] for col in d) for item in c]
```

The parantheses notation creates a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). If you want a tuple instead you need to explicitly state so.

Comment: There's no need for square brackets, `tuple(item[col] for col in d)` works too.